# What are the user level permissions required to add and delete member from Azure active directory security group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am able to add and delete members from azure active directory security group using credentials of Global administrator. what are the permissions or role  need to be assigned for normal user to add and delete member to azure active directory group

Comment: This is the way with least permission to add and delete member from a specific group, otherwise you need to give the user with directory role e.g. global admin. Why you are looking for other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the user to the `Owners` of your group in the portal. Group owners can be users or service principals, and are able to manage the group including membership.

[image]